# Edittext - The limit to number of characters as a function of screen size. Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'd like to have different limits to number of characters in Edittext. That limit must depend upon the screen size. Is it possible to do so? If yes, please share your idea.

Comment: You can do this. Please post the code you tried and tell us where you are having an issue. Is your issue getting the screen size? Or is the issue with limiting the chars for `EditText`?

Comment: My issue is getting the screen size. I haven't penned down the code yet. I'm contemplating before I begin. I hope it's okay if I don't post the code. Although, I'll make sure I will edit the post, either once I successfully implement it, or run into the same problem while writing the code.

Comment: Display myscreen= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int screenWidth = myscreen.getWidth();

now use the width to limit your Edit text.

Comment: What units is `getWidth()` going to return the value in? If you post an answer with more details, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Choose a monospace font and then measure how many characters fit on the screen. That's the only reliable way. If you don't use a monospace font it might still work, but most likely it won't work as well and you are going to have to tweak it a little.

Comment: Or you can create a custom `EditText` with a non scrollable text area.

Comment: @XaverKapeller, I'll have to practically test out monospacefont on each screen, won't I? custom `EditText` sounds good. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It's not necessary to use a monospace font. Although that will increase the performance of the code (since you only need to measure the number of characters once), you could do this using any font. All you need to do is measure the width of the text every time it changes which shouldn't be too expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. What you can do is add a `InputFilter` to the edit text. You can then monitor the change in text width of the edit text. If it ever goes beyond some point, you can just chop off the extras. In this case, you'd want to restrict the text width to the width available for the `EditText`.

Your input filter:

```
public class TextSizeFilter implements InputFilter {
    Paint p;
    int maxWidth;

    /**
     * A filter based on the maxWidth of the text.
     * @param p Paint used by the View
     * @param maxWidth Max width of the text
     */
    public TextSizeFilter(Paint p, int maxWidth) {
        this.p = p;
        this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        float originalW = p.measureText(dest, 0, dstart);
        float spaceLeft = maxWidth - originalW;

        if (spaceLeft > 0) {
            int w = p.breakText(source, start, end, true, spaceLeft, null);

            if (w != source.length())
                return source.subSequence(0, start + w);
        } else {
            return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you need to measure the width of the edit text (and subtract the padding since that space cannot be used) and set the input filter of the edit text.

```
EditText t = ...
int maxWidth = t.getWidth() - t.getPaddingLeft() - t.getPaddingRight(); 
t.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new TextSizeFilter(t.getPaint(), maxWidth)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @idunnololz's answer I made some changes, as that version doesn't seem to work well if the cursor is not at the end of the text, nor does is account for overwriting a text selection.
I also added optionally a maximum amount of characters (so the text will not exceed the view size, nor a limited amount of characters, which ever comes first).

```
public class TextLengthFilter implements InputFilter {

    private final static int NO_MAX_CHARACTERS = -1;

    private Paint p;
    private int maxWidth;
    private int maxCharacters;

    /**
     * A filter based on the maxWidth of the text.
     * @param p Paint used by the View
     * @param maxWidth Max width of the text (in pixels)
     */
    public TextLengthFilter(Paint p, int maxWidth) {
        this(p, maxWidth, NO_MAX_CHARACTERS);
    }

    /**
     * A filter based on the maxWidth of the text.
     * @param p Paint used by the View
     * @param maxWidth Max width of the text (in pixels)
     * @param maxCharacters Max amount of characters for the text
     */
    public TextLengthFilter(Paint p, int maxWidth, int maxCharacters) {
        this.p = p;
        this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
        this.maxCharacters = maxCharacters;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        float originalW = p.measureText(dest, 0, dest.length());
        //Calculate the amount of space that is being reclaimed by characters that are replaced
        int toBeReplacedWidth = p.breakText(dest, dstart, dend, true, originalW, null);
        float spaceLeft = (maxWidth - originalW) + toBeReplacedWidth;
        int selectionLength = (dend - dstart); //The amount of characters that are going to be replaced
        int changeLength = (end - start);

        //Check if there are more characters after the change than before.
        if (maxCharacters != NO_MAX_CHARACTERS && changeLength > selectionLength) {
            //If the length of the original text was already too many characters don't allow more to be added.
            if (dest.length() > maxCharacters) {
                return "";
            }
            int finalLength = dest.length() + changeLength - selectionLength;
            //Check if the final length, after the replacement, doesn't exceed the maximum characters
            if (finalLength > maxCharacters) {
                //if it does limit the characters to be added to not exceed the maximum
                end =  end - (finalLength - maxCharacters);
            }
        }
        //Check if the size of the characters does not exceed the maximum view width
        if (spaceLeft > 0) {
            int w = p.breakText(source, start, end, true, spaceLeft, null) ;
            //If not all characters would fit only allow the ones that do fit
            if (w != source.length())
                return source.subSequence(0, start + w);
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```